# How to add empty columns to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 38 columns. I want to add 19 more blank columns at the end of it.

I've tried this:

```
df.insert([39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57],
              ['Quality Control - Dupe Ticketing/Dupe Invoicing',
                'Error Type',
                'Passed/Not Passed',
                'Agent Name',   
                'Team Leader',  
                'Responsibility(GO/Market/Capability)',
                'Remediation Comments',
                'Financial Exposure/Dupe Value(USD)',
                'Self Identified (Yes/No)',
                'Remediation Date',
                'Remediation Status (Yes/No)',
                'Remarks',
                'CM Impact Yes/No',
                'Is product cost(Air+Land) matching accounting lines & excel file -Yes/No',
                'For Air - all ticket issued and matches all pax',
                'For EXCH Air - passenger association correct & no dupe EXCH',
                'Error - Yes/No',
                'For EXCH Air - penalty check',
                'Comments'],
              empty_value)
```

But this gives a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.`

Comment: what is a "blank column" exactly? Columns must have the same length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.concat`:

```
cols = ['Quality Control - Dupe Ticketing/Dupe Invoicing',
        'Error Type',
        'Passed/Not Passed',
        'Agent Name',   
        'Team Leader',  
        'Responsibility(GO/Market/Capability)',
        'Remediation Comments',
        'Financial Exposure/Dupe Value(USD)',
        'Self Identified (Yes/No)',
        'Remediation Date',
        'Remediation Status (Yes/No)',
        'Remarks',
        'CM Impact Yes/No',
        'Is product cost(Air+Land) matching accounting lines & excel file -Yes/No',
        'For Air - all ticket issued and matches all pax',
        'For EXCH Air - passenger association correct & no dupe EXCH',
        'Error - Yes/No',
        'For EXCH Air - penalty check',
        'Comments']

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=new_columns)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert does not allow for multiple columns. You can try it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': ['a','b','c']})
newcols = ['col3', 'col4']
df[newcols] = None
print(df)
#    col1 col2  col3  col4
# 0     1    a  None  None
# 1     2    b  None  None
# 2     3    c  None  None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add new empty columns doing this:

```
import pandas as pd

new_columns = ['Quality Control - Dupe Ticketing/Dupe Invoicing',
                'Error Type',
                'Passed/Not Passed',
                'Agent Name',   
                'Team Leader',  
                'Responsibility(GO/Market/Capability)',
                'Remediation Comments',
                'Financial Exposure/Dupe Value(USD)',
                'Self Identified (Yes/No)',
                'Remediation Date',
                'Remediation Status (Yes/No)',
                'Remarks',
                'CM Impact Yes/No',
                'Is product cost(Air+Land) matching accounting lines & excel file -Yes/No',
                'For Air - all ticket issued and matches all pax',
                'For EXCH Air - passenger association correct & no dupe EXCH',
                'Error - Yes/No',
                'For EXCH Air - penalty check',
                'Comments']

df.loc[:,new_columns] = pd.DataFrame()
```